# I'm trying to pass the instance of my controller to another controller but it returns null

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a controller that receives data from another(login page) through loading it's fxml

```
fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(UserMainController.class.getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

                //User
                Parent userParent = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                userController = fxmlLoader.<UserMainController>getController();
                userController.setUser(userID, collegeID, username, password, key);
                Scene userScene = new Scene(userParent);

                //get stage information
                Stage window = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

                window.setScene(userScene);
                window.show();
```

this is working fine.
Inside the controller of FXMLDocument.fxml(the one i'm loading above), i'm trying to pass it's instance to other controllers

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        tab1.init(this);
        tab2.init(this);
        tab3.init(this);
}
```

and also inside the fxml of FXMLDocument.fxml, they are included like this

```
                       <BorderPane fx:id="tab1BP">
                       <center>
                           <fx:include fx:id="tab1" source="Tab1/tab1.fxml"/>
                       </center></BorderPane>



                         <BorderPane fx:id="tab2BP" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                         <center>
                             <fx:include fx:id="tab2" source="Tab2/tab2.fxml"/>
                         </center></BorderPane>



                         <BorderPane fx:id="tab3BP">
                         <center>
                             <fx:include fx:id="tab3" source="Tab3/tab3.fxml"/>
                         </center>
                         </BorderPane>
```

I'm getting an error at the line tab3.init(this);

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at ara_thesis.User.UserMainController.initialize(UserMainController.java:149)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 61 more
```

and tab3's initialize function looks like this

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        this.user = userMainController.getUser();
        try {
            initializeProgramTable();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CourseSectionController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
```

it returns null at the line 149 that is
 this.user = userMainController.getUser(); (which is a function inside UserMainController that gets data that came from the login controller.)

and also after trying the built in debugger for netbeans, i found out that tab1.init(this) and tab3.init(this) contains they're controller's instance, as there is a value shown when I hovered above it, and null for tab2.init(this). Removing tab2.init(this) and removing it's inclusion inside the fxml file would result to no errors, so that gave me the conclusion that tab3 is the one with error. But I can't seem to find it. Enclosing tab1.init......tab3.init(this); inside a Platform.runLater would also result to null pointer exception as tab3.initialize would look for a value that would be coming from the usermaincontroller.
Am I missing something here? Thank you for the help

Comment: I wonder why `FXMLDocument.fxml` loads at all. `tab1`, `tab2` and `tab3` are the `fx:id`s used with the `fx:include` elements which means the object created for the root element of the included element is injected to this field, ***not the controller of the fxml***. This should result in an error when loading since `FXMLLoader` should be unable to assign the value for the root element to a field with a type the root's type is not assignable to...

Comment: What should I do? The reason why I'm loading the FXMLDocument.fxml is to pass login information to another controller and change the scene to UserMainController(FXMLDocument.fxml is the view of UserMainController). Then UserMainController contains tabs in it that has different FXMLs and Controllers. I tried to pass the instance of usermaincontroller to all the tabs for them to communicate. Also I want to get a specific id from the login user that will be used for query in tab 3

Comment: Usually you just need to append `Controller` to the `fx:id` of the `<fx:include>` to get the name of the field you need to use for the controller of the included fxml. However i don't know why your code does not fail in the first place... Furthermore why not move the code you used with `Platform.runLater` to the `init` method instead?

Comment: Can you show the parts where you set `userMainController` in the tabs? Why do you say the error is at `tab3.init(this)` but the stack trace points to `initialize` method? Can you also show the code of `init`?

Comment: @Gnas yes it says that tab3.init(this) was null. And another error below that, points to the initialize method of tab3 which is the one above. Here is the code for init: 'public void init(UserMainController userMainController) {
        this.userMainController = userMainController;
    }'

Comment: @fabian can you give an example? I'm sorry as I can't understand it clearly

Comment: Why you set `this.user = userMainController.getUser()` line in `PLatfrom.runLater()` ?

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine because based at some of the things I've researched, it says that values passed from one controller to another would not be accessible at initialize() function unless until the window is fully loaded. And that's what I've found they are using, Platform.runLater()

Comment: I figured it out. I've been stuck with the error for a long time, and now I only get what you meant by adding controller to the fx:id after tinkering with it for a while. So at the @FXML declaration of the class, it should be (fx:id + Controller). Thanks for the help! It's my bad that I didn't figured it out right away.